# Finding the values of a and b in the function $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

So I have to find the values of $a$ and $b$ in the function $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$.  What I have is that the function has the tangent line $2y + 4x = 2$ at the point $(2,5)$.

Not quite sure how to solve this.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The equation of the tangent in $x_0$ is $y=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition is that $f(2)=5$, because it passes through $(2,5)$ which gives
$$2a+b=1$$
The slope of the line $2y+4x=2$ is $-2$. Since $f(x)$ is tangent to it at $(2,5)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
f'(2)&=-2\\
4+a&=-2\\
a&=-6
\end{align}
$$
Which gives $b=13$